# Does tf.data API make use of tf.placeholders under the hood?

Tags: tensorflow

I am wondering if `tf.data` API is using `tf.placeholders` under the hood, and if creating `tf.data.Dataset` is like creating a separate computational graph in which we load preprocess data and then merge with computational graph that our model represents?

Comment: This is a bit of a strange question. I don't think `tf.data` uses placeholders anywhere, in fact placeholders are deprecated in TF 2.x. `tf.data` specific operations are part of the graph when not in eager mode, although I think they usually run on the CPU (they are not so well suited for GPU, and in any case the idea is that your input pipeline runs on CPU and the model on GPU). Can you expand a bit on why you are asking the question and how would the answer impact you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.data` does not use `tf.placeholders` under the hood. `tf.data.Dataset` uses the same mechanisms as other Tensorflow ops. The graph it creates in graph mode is not separate.

Check out the below video to learn more about how `tf.data` works under the hood. I linked to the part that explains what happens when you call `next()` on a dataset iterator.

https://youtu.be/kVEOCfBy9uY?t=1404